# Problema com porcentagem decimal do processador - JAVA

Tags: java, porcentagem

Bom gente, o problema é o seguinte, desenvolvi um código para pegar a porcentagem utilizada pela minha aplicação dos núcleos do processador:

```
private String getCPULoad() {
    OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return (df.format(osBean.getProcessCpuLoad())) + "%";
}
```

Na teoria ele deveria me devolver a porcentagem, pois bem ele devolve, só que da forma errada, por exemplo: quando todos os núcleos estão sento utilizados a 100%, ele deveria me devolver a porcentagem "100%", mas ao invés disso ele me devolve 0,1%, alguém poderia me dizer oque estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuLoad--), o método `getProcessCpuLoad` retorna um `double` entre 0.0 e 1.0, portanto basta multiplicar o valor por 100.

Comment: Se os dados foram realmente levantados corretamente, ainda assim isso corresponderia a 10% de CPU (`0.1 * 100`), o que entra em conflito com a afirmação de que estava usando todos os núcleos a 100%

Comment: Na realidade seria multiplicar por 1000, mas por algum motivo eu não estou conseguindo fazer esta multiplicação